# Display data of InfoPath form in a page

Tags: infopath

I have a SharePoint 2010 list which is customized from InfoPath designer and published back to SharePoint list.I have columns Name , LoginName, Address and Email. when a user fills the data in the form and saved in the list. I want to show the data in the home page of my site as form whenever a user is logged in and he should see the data belongs to him from the form. Is it possible I tried InfoPath form web-part but cannot achieve it .are there nay other options to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you try with the InfoPath form you used in a web part?

If the LoginName is the same as the value returned by the userName() function in InfoPath you could add a form load rule to your InfoPath form that:

1. Sets the LoginName query field in your data connection to the list to the username function
2. Queries the data connection to the list

This should just return the items for this user - then you could display those in the form.

Comment: Hi Hilary Am looking to show the items of list which were filled through InfoPath form on a SharePoint Page upon logged on user